# Can't connect to Steam servers and other gaming servers on Windows 10

Tags: steam, networking, war-thunder

I have been having an issue with Steam. Whenever I try to log into it, it tells me that it is having trouble connecting to the Steam servers, and won't let me log in. I used to be able to use Steam perfectly fine, but I started getting issues after I moved.

I have tried re-installing, deleting ClientRegistry.blob, and everything else. I even tried replacing my router, as it was a bit out of date. Despite all of these, none of them have helped.

I am also having issues connecting to the Warthunder servers outside of Steam.  It says I have limited Ethernet, but I am able to use the internet on my computer. Another thing that is not working are .io websites. I am unable to connect to them.

Despite these things, I am able to use the browser version of steam.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall rules?

Comment: @TheBird956 yeah, but they didnt change during the move, and they worked before the move.

Comment: This almost sounds like the network is set up to block various sites/ports. Are you on a college/university/work network? Did you set up the router you are using?

Comment: @Angzuril I am on a home network, but I didn't set it up myself.

Comment: `Win + R -> "inetcpl.cpl" -> Connections -> LAN Settings` .. Is the Proxy disabled?

Comment: @dly The proxy is disabled.

Comment: Can you log into Steam through the website?

Comment: @Sorean yes, I am able to use the browser version of steam.

Comment: Are you using a VPN service to connect to the internet?

Also, have you switched Internet Service Provider recently?

Thirdly, have you gone through [Steam Connection Troubleshooting](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1456-EUDN-2493)?:

Comment: What kind of antivirus or firewall software are you running? If you turn those off, does Steam connect?

Comment: @DrFish I am not using a VPN or a proxy to connect to the internet. I have switched internet providers recently, and I did try using the Steam Connection Troubleshooting, but it did not help.

Comment: @Sorean I tried to disabling the firewall, but that did not help.

Comment: Did your ISP recently change their IPv6 offering? Steam doesn't like IPv6 yet, so if your ISP is doing some funny IPv6 to IPv4 routing you could run into trouble.

Comment: @SirAdelaide would that have any impact on the issues that are not related to steam?

Answer (score 3):

Your ISP is likely transitioning to IPv6 using "IPv6 Dual-Stack Lite" or similar. In this method:

> When a user’s device sends an IPv4 packet to an external destination, DS-Lite encapsulates the IPv4 packet in an IPv6 packet for transport into the provider network. Tunneling IPv4 over IPv6 is simpler than translation and eliminates performance and redundancy concerns.

Other Steam users have reported similar problems (thus my assumption):
https://superuser.com/questions/1051632/translating-ipv6-packets-to-ipv4-packets-to-reach-a-game-server

Solutions:

- Confirm with your ISP that they are in fact using an IPv6 Dual Stack Lite configuration
- ask your ISP for a proper IPv4 address
- or, try the instructions from that link. They look a bit more complicated than talking to your ISP though.

Comment: You the differences between IPv6 and IPv4 effect more than just Steam? My issue expands more than just Steam, its just one of the biggest things effected.

Comment: yes, it certainly could affect more than just Steam. You could try asking on SuperUser with details of your .io connection problems if my answer here doesn't help

Comment: What type of details would I need to use in my question on SuperUser?

Comment: Would getting a new modem help anything? Or would it still rely on the ISP.

Comment: if putting on Superuser, results of trace route (http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/troubleshooter/traceroute.html) to steam and a .io site would be useful, as would details of your DNS settings in your router, and which ISP you use. You said you already tried a new router, so include that info also.